# Javascript beginner question: Bool or Int?

Tags: javascript, web, optimization, integer, boolean

I'm a Javascript beginner and I want to ask why a thing is happening in my code

```js
var whoisplaying = 2;


function laX(lid) {
  if (whoisplaying == 2) {
    document.getElementById(lid).textContent = "X";
    minus();
  } else {
    prompt("hi");
    plus();
  }
}

function minus() {
  whoisplaying = 1;
}

function plus() {
  whoisplaying = 2;
}
```

On this one above I have no issues on the on click function applied to a few buttons, while if I set the var whosiplaying as a bool as im gonna show in the next snippet, it doesnt work: the else statment will never be working, the var will always be true.

```js
var whoisplaying = true;


function laX(lid) {
  if (whoisplaying == true) {
    document.getElementById(lid).textContent = "X";
    minus();
  } else {
    prompt("hi");
    plus();
  }
}

function minus() {
  whoisplaying = false;
}

function plus() {
  whoisplaying = true;
}
```

Can someone explain me why, so I'll not make mistakes in the future? Thanks you.

Comment: What do you mean both will work the same! where is the difference?!

Comment: try using `let` instead of `var`

Comment: If the two don't work the same, it's not in this code. You have to provide us with a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you have because currently we cannot diagnose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the two examples of yours, they behave the same way!, note that `if(whoisplaying == true)` could just be `if(whoisplaying)` when you check against booleans

**Using Numbers**

```js
var whoisplaying = 2;

function laX() {
  if(whoisplaying == 2) {
    document.getElementById("lid").textContent="X";    
    minus();    
  }else {
    prompt("hi");
    plus();
  }
}

function minus() {
  whoisplaying = 1;
}

function plus() {
  whoisplaying = 2;
}
```

```html
<p id="lid"></p>
<button onclick="laX()">Click me</button>
```

**Using Booleans**

```js
var whoisplaying = true;

function laX() {
  if(whoisplaying == true) {
    document.getElementById("lid").textContent="X";    
    minus();    
  }else {
    prompt("hi");
    plus();
  }
}

function minus() {
  whoisplaying = false;
}

function plus() {
  whoisplaying = true;
}
```

```html
<p id="lid"></p>
<button onclick="laX()">Click me</button>
```

Ok since you have added a comment that says

> Don't ask me why but using boolenas it wasn't working when I tried it before... the else statement wasn't working...now it works both way.

I realised that the mistake was a typo in your code, I think you have typed `=` instead of `==` in your if statement although the given code doesn't have that typo, so that makes the if statement assign the `true` value each time to that variable and the returned value from that expression is truthy so the else never executes, but always the body of the if statement executes, here is an example

```html
<p id="lid"></p>
<button onclick="laX()">Click me</button>
```

**Using Booleans**

```js
var whoisplaying = true;

function laX() {
  if(whoisplaying = true) {
    document.getElementById("lid").textContent="X";    
    minus();    
  }else {
    prompt("hi");
    plus();
  }
}

function minus() {
  whoisplaying = false;
}

function plus() {
  whoisplaying = true;
}
```

```html
<p id="lid"></p>
<button onclick="laX()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Don't ask me why but using boolenas it wasn't working when I tried it before... the else statement wasn't working...now it works both way. Thanks!

Comment: @Jab Ok I think You had a typo in your code, just `=` instead of `==`, I have updated my answer, check it out

Comment: yeah i guess it is like you're saying, infact it was always true